# Convert coefficients from log odds to marginal effects with imputed data in R

Tags: r, regression, cluster-analysis, logistic-regression, glm

I am using multiple imputation on missing data and then using the pool_mi function to get coefficients. Since my data is clustered I also had to calculate cluster robust SE my regression model using the lm.cluster function. However the output for the coefficients is in log odds form I believe. How can I convert the coefficients to be marginal effects? Or if that is not possible to be in probabilities? I've tried to follow this posts (linked [here](https://rpubs.com/OmaymaS/182726)) but can't figure it out since my situation is a bit more complicated...  Below is the example code for what I have done with the function and images of the output. Thank you!

```
library(mitools)
library(miceadds)
data(data.ma05)
dat <- data.ma05

# imputation of the dataset: use six imputations
resp <- dat[, - c(1:2) ]
imp <- mice::mice( resp, method="norm", maxit=3, m=6 )
datlist <- miceadds::mids2datlist( imp )

# linear regression with cluster robust standard errors
mod <- lapply(  datlist, FUN=function(data){
            miceadds::lm.cluster( data=data, formula=denote ~ migrant+ misei,
                    cluster=dat$idclass )
            }  )
# extract parameters and covariance matrix
betas <- lapply( mod, FUN=function(rr){ coef(rr) } )
vars <- lapply( mod, FUN=function(rr){ vcov(rr) } )
# conduct statistical inference
summary( miceadds::pool_mi( qhat=betas, u=vars ) )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the `datlist` using `for loop` to calculate cluster robust SE of you regression model using the `lm_robust` function. In assigning mod using lapply by default takes a closure type object that is not subsettable:

```r
library(estimatr)
mod <- vector('list', length(datlist))
for(i in seq_along(datlist)){
  for(j in seq_along(datlist[[i]])){
    mod[[i]]<- lm_robust( data=datlist[[i]], formula=denote ~ migrant+ misei,
                          cluster=dat$idclass )
  }
}
```

Now use the `margins` function to find the marginal effects:

```r
library(margins)
mod_margins <- list()
for(i in seq_along(mod)){
  mod_margins[[i]] <- margins::marginal_effects(mod[[i]])
}

# For single model in `mod`:
mar_cl <- margins::margins(mod[[1]])
mar_cl
```

Output:

```r
migrant    misei
   0.5186 -0.01396
```

Comment: Great! Thank you so much. So this is the average marginal effect right? Is there a way to have the final output also show the p-value and SE in following columns?

Comment: All are inclusive in the `mod` vector. when you run `mod` in the terminal, you will have the same output as yours for each of the six imputations.
For a single model: `mod[[1]]$p-value`, 
SE: `mod[[1]]$std.error`

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Comment: one other follow up question for you. In the final lines of code you show how to show the ME for a single model from one of the imputation trials, but is there a way to get the marginal effects after pooling the results from all 6 of the imputations?